# Automatic non-RESTful routes in Rails 3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, routes

We have an app with a large number of non-RESTful, verb-oriented controllers.  I remember that long ago, before Rails got the REST religion, you could get automatic routes and helpers for those.  Is there any way to still do this? It's a pain to keep adding GETs every time we add an action, and our app (or perhaps our collective development brain) just doesn't lend itself to RESTfulness.

Comment: just a tip: you can be RESTful without adhering to the insanely narrow Rails REST-style / conventions. and don't confuse REST with CRUD. (just because CRUD maps perfectly, it doesn't mean, it's the only way to be RESTful). basically if you identify resources by distinct URLs and use the HTTP verbs according to specification (e.g. PUT and DELETE must be idempotent etc, POST only for changing data, GET always without sideeffects), you're already RESTful

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the "magic route", I believe it's still in the routes file by default, but if you don't have it here it is:

```
# This is a legacy wild controller route that's not recommended for RESTful applications.
# Note: This route will make all actions in every controller accessible via GET requests.
# match ':controller(/:action(/:id(.:format)))'
```

Answer (score 2):

You can still use a default route like this:

```
match ':controller(/:action(/:id))'
```

to match paths like

- /monkey/play
- /monkey/see/1
- /monkey/hear/1
- /monkey/eat/1